# Nginx conflicting with angular 6 routes

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-router

I have an angular 6 app with base href set to `/dashboard/`.
The built files a located on the server, generated with the `--prod` flags.

nginx conf looks like:

```
location /dashboard {
    alias /<path_to_built_files>/frontend/dist/frontend/;
}
```

When I first hit my website with say, `example.com/dashboard`,
application loads perfectly and angular redirects to default route `/create`.
Hence browser shows my route as `example.com/dashboard/create`.

This is exactly how I want it to behave.
However if I reload the page from here, browser tried to find `example.com/dashboard/create`, which returns 404 Not Found.

What am I doing wrong in the configuration here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an index file and a redirect if it can't find a file on the path to `index.html`:

```
location /dashboard {
  alias /<path_to_built_files>/frontend/dist/frontend/;
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You could use ***hash*** ***[location strategy](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/)***, which helps remembering URL for browsers. *It uses the hash fragment part of the URL to store state for the client, it easier to setup and doesn’t require any co-operation from the server side*. So, just add `useHash` in your router configuration as follows -

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

Then you could rebuild your application & deploy to production. You'll see a `#` added to your URL.

Comment: I do not want the `#` coming in my urls

Comment: You may try `PathLocationStrategy`, but I'm **not sure** that it will help you!